# How should we treat Minecraft Command questions that do not include any kind of code?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I've noticed an influx in [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands) questions recently where the questions do not have any kind of code.  Take [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/310666/a-redstone-torch-that-can-only-be-placed-on-green-wool-in-minecraft-pe) and [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/310811/minecraft-item-command) for example.

Now, on StackOverflow, there is a flag/close reason for these kind of questions:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Granted we are not StackOverflow, how should we deal with these kind of questions?  I'm fine with Minecraft Command questions that include code that has been supplied by the asker, but when the question does not include any code that the asker attempted to use, what should be done?

Comment: Another example: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/310831/villager-trade-enchanted-book

Comment: If the asker does not give enough information, close as 'unclear what you're asking'. I figured we were doing this already for commands questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion like the homework questions over on the Chemistry SE, the asker should at least show some effort at solving the problem themselves. I personally would ask them to at least include an effort to make a commend to achieve what they want, simply to show some effort/understanding themselves.